# Como conseguir a medalha Limpeza?

Tags: suporte, medalhas

[image: Medalha Limpeza]

Como conseguir a medalha limpeza?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basta fazer reverter (quase um <kbd>control + Z</kbd>) uma publicação a um versão anterior. Entre no histórico da publicação e click no link `reverter`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Também estava procurando por essa informação. Valeu! :)